# Doubts on buttons, hidden tag and input image

Tags: html

I am planning to add a button on the site and this is my syntax.and it appears like this:

```
 <button> <image src="add.jpg" width="50" height="10"/> </button>
```

[image]

1)I don't want the gray box but only the yellow box. How do I achieve it? (If I write 'add+' outside the tags then it appears in the gray box.Hence 'add+' is an image.)

2) what is the difference in  <**button**> tag and <**input type ="image"**> tag because they both create buttons. Am I missing something?

3) what does <**input type="hidden"**> do? Can you give me an example.

Comment: Can someone tell me why my questions always get negatives? I mean isn't this place for people who have doubts?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for input type "hidden", just click on "Run code snippet" and you will see what a hidden input is.

```html
<input type="hidden" value="iAmHidden"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1) I don't want the gray box but only the yellow box. How do I achieve
>   it? (If I write 'add+' outside the tags then it appears in the gray
>   box.Hence 'add+' is an image.)

It's up to you to define how you want to style the button. Just modify its appearance by CSS.

> 2) what is the difference in `<button>` tag and `<input type ="image">`
>   tag because they both create buttons. Am I missing something?

They are basically two differens ways to create the same kind of element. The button element was introduced to make the developers life easier. E.g the possibility to nest elements.

> 3) what does `<input type="hidden">` do? Can you give me an example.

A hidden input is a way to store a value which is hidden from the user. E.g when you want to post additional form values to a server side script.

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="image">` doesn't really make a button, it just makes a clickable image.  It's not widely used because frankly it isn't very useful, and its behavior is inconsistent between browsers.

When you use a `<button>` to submit a form, its `name` and `value` attributes are sent back to the server.  This lets you, if you need to, tell which button was clicked.

An `<input type="image">` also can submit a form, but when you do, something different happens.  Instead of sending its name and value like with a normal button, your browser will send its name and the coordinates of where you clicked the image.  For example, if you click near the top-left corner of the image, the coordinates will be close to (0, 0).  This is pretty much useless, because the only situations I can think of where you'd want to know that are things like interactive maps, which you should handle client-side with JavaScript anyway.

Some browsers, like Chrome, will *also* add the `<input type="image">` name and value.  But since only some browsers do that, you can't rely on it in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btn1{
    color:black;
    background-color:yellow;
    width:50;
    height:50;
    padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn1">add+</button>
```